# dynamic cell height in ios using constrain programatically in swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nslayoutconstraint, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am working on a project in swift which needs the cell size to be dynamic according to the label content, so i searched for dynamic cell height, i found some solution but all of it included use of storyboard for assigning constrain. Is it possible to do it without storyboard. Is it possible to do it programatically? I mean applying self sizing without storyboard

my code is:

```
class a: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.view.addSubview(tableView)
}
```

Hope the question is clear.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: None of the answers below is helpful

Comment: Please check https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-8-tutorial-series-auto-sizing-table-cells

Answer (score 1):

Try this method.

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
 return // get cell text label high and return +10 or +20 height. what is label height..
}
```

Comment: i want to use self sizing cell, can u tell about that?

Answer (score 1):

- iOS 7 compatible: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayout
- iOS 8 only: https://github.com/smileyborg/TableViewCellWithAutoLayoutiOS8

Answer (score 1):

You can try this method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
 self.dashBoardTableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    if (CellIdentifier == "dashBoardTableCellID")
    {
       dashBoardTableView.rowHeight =  96
    }
    else
    {
        dashBoardTableView.rowHeight =  60
    }

    return self.dashBoardTableView.rowHeight
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, you can create your constraints in code.
I suggest you look at the class NSLayoutConstraint:

[NSLayoutConstraint Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSLayoutConstraint_Class/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

iOS 8 suppoorts self sized tableview cells. To enable it first create your cell with correct constraints. End use code below

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
tableView.cellHeight = UITableViewCellAutomaticDimension
```

`estimatedRowHeight` is just hint for tableview. When tableview reuses cells it looks its content and adjust sizes acoording to it.

Comment: i know that, i want to know how can i do it i mean code